# Can't access 'local' XML file

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to access a 'local' xml file stored within my project prior to parsing it.

However, I cannot seem to access the XML file I have created.

My code is as  follows

```
self.fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//get array of paths
self.paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//get documents directory path
self.documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

self.file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mylocalfile.xml"];
```

The file is stored in the root of the project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say

> The file is stored in the root of the project.

But then you look for it in the *Documents* directory. Instead, do this:

```
self.file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mylocalfile" ofType:@"xml"];
```

Note that capitalization matters.